# R gRain error - table dimensions do not match

Tags: r, bayesian

I am creating a Bayesian network using the gRain package in R. When trying to compile the conditional probability tables, I get the error 'Table dimensions do not match'. The table in question takes the form A|B, where A can take three possible values and B can take two. I have entered a total of 12 values in the cptable definition based on the six possible combinations. Any help would be much appreciated as I have checked and researched to no avail and can't see what's going wrong. This is my code.

```
# define levels
lh <- c("low", "high")
lmh <- c("low", "medium", "high")

# specify the conditional probability tables
eh <- cptable(~eh, values=c(0.2, 0.8), levels=lh)
inf.oil.eh <- cptable(~inf | oil:eh, values = c(0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1, 0.9, 0.01, 0.99), levels=lh)
bp.oil <- cptable(~bp | oil, values=c(0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0, 1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.4, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5), levels=lmh)
oil.eh <- cptable(~oil | eh, values=c(0.9, 0.1, 0.05, 0.95), levels=lh)
rt.inf.eh <-cptable(~rt | inf:eh, values=c(0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1, 0.9, 0.01, 0.99), levels=lh)
# compile the tables
plist <- compileCPT(list(eh, oil.eh, inf.oil.eh, bp.oil, rt.inf.eh))
```

The error is as follows:

```
    Error for v,pa(v): bp, oil
    List of 2
     $ bp : chr [1:3] "low" "medium" "high"
     $ oil: chr [1:2] "low" "high"
     num [1:12] 0.9 0.1 0.1 0.9 0 1 0.1 0.9 0.4 0.6 ...
        Error in compileCPT(list(eh, oil.eh, inf.oil.eh, bp.oil, rt.inf.eh)) : 
      Table dimensions do not match!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying too many values for the conditional probability table for `bp|oil`. Since `oil` has 2 levels and `bp` 3 you need 6 conditional probabilities but you have 12 in the line

```
bp.oil <- cptable(~bp | oil, values=c(0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0, 1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.4, 0.6, 0.5, 0.5), levels=lmh)
```

Comment: Thanks Harald - I was getting used to adding in the pairs of p, 1-p for the two-value variables and did the same thing here!

Comment: @Kate How did you solve this problem? I am getting the exact error and the same question